# PhoneGap + jQuery android app; ajax request runs in browser but not on phone or emulator

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, soap, basic-authentication

I am working on an app which has to load data from a Microsoft Dynamics NAV SOAP web service. When I run the code in a browser (IE9 or Chrome v 26.0...) the code does what it should. But when I test the code on an android emulator or a real device (htc sensation) the ajax call fails and I get the XMLHttpRequest error 0.

However, I could also load data from different web-services without basic authentication on android systems.

My whitelist (located in res/xml/config.xml) looks like this:

```
<access origin="*" />

<plugins>
    ... // all other possible plugins
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
</plugins>
```

and here the code:

```
function readTimeRecords(callback) {

var wsUrl = 'http://.../WS/CRONUS%20AG/Page/Time_Recording';

var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + 
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' + 
    '<soap:Body>' + 
        '<ReadMultiple xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/time_recording" >' +
            '<filter>' +
                '<Field>No</Field>' +
            '</filter>' +
            '<bookmarkKey />' +
            '<setSize>' +
                '5' +
            '</setSize>' +
        '</ReadMultiple>' +
     '</soap:Body> ' + 
 '</soap:Envelope>';

// enable cross site requests in IE
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

$.ajax({
    url : wsUrl,
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "text",
    data : soapMessage,
    processData : false,
    contentType : "text/xml", 

    password : "passwd",
    username : "domain\\user",

    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/time_recording');
    },
    success : function(msg) {
        ...     
        callback(record);
    },
    error : onError 
})  
}

function onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    debugger;
    console.log("error: " + textStatus + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        // i just get the message error: error:
}
```

Does someone know how to fix that issue?

used setup:
jquery.mobile-1.3.0
jquery-19.1
cordova-2.5

Comment: @user2289828 Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For CORS to work, your web service must be CORS enabled. Here is a [good writeup](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) . If you cannot CORS enable your service, using JSONP instead of JSON is the other option.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I thought same origin policy does only affect browsers and not apps on mobile devices. Therefore I don't have to use CORS.
However, I can execute the code in IE and Chrome (--disable-web-security) and it works perfektly. 

Furthermore I can't use JSON or JSONP because the soap web service only provides the data in XML.

Comment: Thats right... Mobile Apps an do cross domain calls. if you are running the app as a website in the emulator, CORS enabling of service is required. Can you see what is the status code and error returned using XMLHttpRequest.status and XMLHttpRequest.statusText

Comment: status = 0
statusText = "error"

ok, so you are saying that a phonegap app is more behaving like a webpage than a native app and I need to use CORS in order to run the web service?

Comment: Nope. your initial assumption is correct. What i meant to say is that if you are hosting the app using a web server like IIS and then accessing it using emulator browser, then CORS is required. If you are installing the .apk file in the emulator and running it, then you dont have to CORS enable the service.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that to me. For test purpose I always install the .apk file. So the problem shouldn’t be a cross origin request. I can’t imagine what causes the error. I even checked whether the web service target url is accessible. I would be grateful for any advices locating the error.

Comment: Can you try using plain JavaScript instead of jQuery with the help of this post: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html . See this thread too: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/wdQ4ga5Lkp0

Comment: ok, now I implemented my soap client without jQuery and could successfully load the data in the browser (using XMLHttpRequest) . Unfortunately this also won’t work on the android emulator. So the code can’t be the problem. Is there some configuration to consider beneath whitelist or is it possible that my whitelist won’t work.

Comment: PhoneGap's default policy is now allow all network access. So white listing could not be a problem.